# How to use NOT ONLY CONTAINS operation in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

My application will rotate through the logs and print the output(s) as

`<some data> ; no issues`   or `no issues`

I am trying to write a powershell script on this output to create a report. The output of powershell should be

1. `<some data>` if the output of the logs is `<some data> ; no issues`
2. `no issues` if the output of the logs is `no issues`

`no issues` can appear in any part of the output. It is not appeared in a static position. Please see below:

case1: `<data1>;no issues;<data2>`

case2: `<any data>;no issues`

case3: `no issues;<any data>`

Basically, I need to print like if the output of the logs contains any data along with no issues, it should print only the data and should not print no issues. The other side, if the output of the logs contains only no issues then it should print no issues.

In this case, I am trying to see a **NOT ONLY CONTAINS** condition (if available) through powershell. Can anyone help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: Try `-split`ting on `no issues`; if what's left is empty, it's a `no issues` case; if it's *not* empty, it's data.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string on `;` and discard anything but the first substring returned - if no data is present, you'll get the existing string `"no issues"`, otherwise you'll get the data:

```
Get-Content path\to\log\file |ForEach-Object {
  $_ -split ';' |Select -First 1
}
```

Comment: @karthik Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68087473/edit) with some sample data if it's not as described

Answer (score 0):

```
# test data to simulate log
$text = @'
<data1>;no issues;<data2>
<any data>;no issues
no issues;<any data>
no issues
some other stuff
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# use switch with -regex tag to check for lines that contain 'no issue'
switch -regex ($text) {
    # if line matches 'no issues'
    'no issues' {
        # if semi-colon is found, remove 'no issues' and trim off any ; and whitespace from begining and end
        if ($_ -match ';') {
            ($_ -replace 'no issues' -replace ';{2,}', ';').Trim(';').Trim()
        } else {
            # if no semi-colon just output line as-is (expected 'no issues')
            $_
        }
    }
    # if line doesn't match 'no issues' just output it
    Default {$_}
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<data1>;<data2>
<any data>
<any data>
no issues
some other stuff
```